# Cannot pair/connect to my headphones : Failure: Module initialization failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I'm using linux kernel v4.4.0-148 and bluez v5.36.

I cannot pair nor connect to my bluetooth headphones Muse "M-260 BT" with `bluetoothctl` :

```bsh
$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A seb-C70D-B-311 [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A Class: 0x00010c
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A Powered: yes
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 M-260 BT
[bluetooth]# scan off
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A Discovering: no
Discovery stopped
[bluetooth]# pair 00:13:09:01:19:61 
Attempting to pair with 00:13:09:01:19:61
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# paired-devices 
Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 M-260 BT
[bluetooth]# connect 00:13:09:01:19:61 
Attempting to connect to 00:13:09:01:19:61
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]# quit
[DEL] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A seb-C70D-B-311 [default]
```

The bluetooth service is running :

```bsh
$ sudo initctl status bluetooth 
bluetooth start/spawned, process 1628
```

But the syslog says `bluetoothd[1628]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 00:13:09:01:19:61: Protocol not available` although the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package is already installed :

```bsh
$ grep bluetoothd /var/log/syslog | tail -5
Jun 30 17:25:31 seb-C70D-B-311 bluetoothd[1628]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 30 17:53:44 seb-C70D-B-311 bluetoothd[1628]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 00:13:09:01:19:61: Protocol not available
Jun 30 17:53:52 seb-C70D-B-311 bluetoothd[1628]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 00:13:09:01:19:61: Protocol not available
Jun 30 18:01:57 seb-C70D-B-311 bluetoothd[1628]: Failed to confirm name for hci0: Failed (0x03)
Jun 30 18:08:20 seb-C70D-B-311 bluetoothd[1628]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 00:13:09:01:19:61: Protocol not available
$ dpkg -l pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-===================================================================
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth     1:4.0-0ubuntu11      amd64                Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

EDIT0 : Noticed the `module-bluetooth-discover` was not loaded, so I tried to load it but it fails :

```bsh
$ pactl list modules short | grep module-bluetooth-discover
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my pb. by updating the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package from the [Launchpad ppa:tigerite/bluez5 PPA](http://launchpad.net/%7Etigerite/+archive/ubuntu/bluez5/) :

```bsh
$ wget -nv https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/bluez5/+files/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4_amd64.deb
2020-08-30 00:23:20 URL:https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/bluez5/+files/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4_amd64.deb [112370/112370] -> "pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4_amd64.deb" [1]
$ sudo gdebi -n pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
(Reading database ... 588813 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4) over (1:4.0-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:6.0-0ubuntu6ppa4) ...
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
39
$ pactl list modules short | grep module-bluetooth
38  module-bluetooth-policy     
39  module-bluetooth-discover
```

And now it works fine :

```bsh
$ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 34:E6:AD:A1:9B:8A seb-C70D-B-311 [default]
[NEW] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 M-260 BT
[bluetooth]# connect 00:13:09:01:19:61 
Attempting to connect to 00:13:09:01:19:61
[CHG] Device 00:13:09:01:19:61 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[M-260 BT]#
```